# ¿Qué extensión de PHP usar para manejar más de 30 millones de datos en MySQL: MySQLi, PDO o Eloquent en PHP nativo?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, eloquent, pdo

Tengo un proyecto en PHP en el que debo manejar una base de datos de gran escala con más de 30 millones de registros en MySQL. Estoy tratando de tomar una decisión informada sobre qué extensión de PHP sería la más adecuada para esta tarea. ¿Debería usar MySQLi, PDO o considerar el uso de Eloquent (parte de Laravel) en PHP nativo?

Mi objetivo principal es garantizar un rendimiento óptimo, una gestión eficiente de la memoria y la capacidad de escalar el proyecto si es necesario en el futuro. Me preocupa especialmente la velocidad de acceso a los datos y la seguridad de las consultas.

Agradecería mucho cualquier consejo o experiencia que puedan compartir con respecto a estas opciones y cuál podría ser la más adecuada para un proyecto de esta magnitud.

Answer (score 2):

Me parece que tienes un proyecto muy interesante. Una base de datos de 30 millones de registros es una gran cantidad de datos, y es importante elegir la extensión de PHP adecuada para manejarlos.

En general, te recomendaría usar PDO para este proyecto. PDO es una extensión de bajo nivel que proporciona un acceso directo a la base de datos. Esto significa que puede ser más eficiente que las extensiones de alto nivel como MySQLi.

PDO también es una extensión escalable que puede manejar grandes cantidades de datos. Esto es importante para tu proyecto, ya que es probable que la base de datos crezca en el futuro.

Por último, PDO proporciona funciones para proteger tus datos contra ataques SQL. Esto es importante para cualquier proyecto, pero es especialmente importante para proyectos de gran escala que almacenan datos confidenciales.

Por supuesto, hay algunas cosas que puedes hacer para mejorar el rendimiento de PDO para proyectos de gran escala. Aquí hay algunos consejos:

- Optimiza tus consultas SQL: Usa consultas SQL eficientes que eviten
  el acceso innecesario a la base de datos.
- Usa la caché: La caché
  puede ayudar a mejorar el rendimiento de las consultas que se
  ejecutan con frecuencia.
- Evita las consultas SELECT masivas: Las
  consultas SELECT masivas pueden consumir mucha memoria.
- Escala tu base de datos: Si tu base de datos crece, es posible que
  necesites escalarla para mantener el rendimiento.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que deberías analizar cual es el objetivo de tu base de datos, si pretendes escalar dicha base a Oracle u otro motor, tu código PHP en PDO no tendrías mayor problema, por otro lado:

-PDO no es de bajo nivel es solo una abstracción de acceso a los datos tanto como MySQLi.

La cual te permite trabajar de manera standard entre un motor u otro, la ventaja que tiene PDO como te lo mencione anteriormente es que viene todo empaquetado en una librería y compatible con mas motores.

-Mysqli por otro lado es una librería diseñada específicamente para MySql.

Con lo cual proporcionaría ciertas ventajas en cuanto a algunas instrucciones especificas. Es una decisión que debes tomar en base a la necesidad que tengas y cual es la proyección al futuro, a favor de mysqli la programación es mas sencilla y también se puede programar orientado a objetos (POO), con lo cual no habría diferencia en cuanto a PDO, por otra parte también puedes usar consultas preparadas y las típicas acciones que puedes tomar para evitar las inyecciones SQL. en cuanto a su performance he leído un un articulo en el cual mysqli es un 2.5% mas rápido que PDO, pero esa cifra tampoco es tanto como para tomar una determinación, igualmente el articulo es de ya una década.

[PDO vs. MySQLi: Which Should You Use?](https://code.tutsplus.com/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059t)

Seria interesante encontrar algún articulo actual con las performance actualizadas.

En conclusión la decisión esta en tus manos, sea cual sea seguramente será la correcta.

Comment: ¿Tienes alguna opinión de usar la librería de eloquent?

Comment: Si estas trabajando con un framework como laravel no es necesario que te esfuerces por PDO o por Mysqli ya que eloquent hace lo mismo que PDO, de hecho esta mas orientado a la producción, pero claro no tendrás tanto control sobre el detalle fino de las consultas como en mysqli o pdo.

Comment: trabajo con php nativo, cual deberia de usar la libreria de eloquent?,o  pdo, mysqli?